# How would I input this terminal command using command line?

Tags: windows, unix, command-line, terminal

I'm used to using terminal, so for example if I want an executable to run a file, in terminal I would type: ./gulp < EMM24.gin 
where gulp is the exe file and EMM24.gin is the input file for it.
How would I do this in cmd on Windows?

Comment: `gulp < EMM24.gin`...

Comment: Or, a more literal transliteration - `.\gulp < EMM24.gin` - including the current directory designation. The only difference would be M$'s oddball fascination with `\\` for a path separator...